# CSS - Setting element's width and height to zero

Tags: html, css

Have a div with padding of 30px, and width and height of 100px. Box sizing is set to border box. When trying to set the width and height to zero, it does not work. Element stays at 60px X 60px dimensions. (Even with the overflow set to hidden).

Any idea what's going on here? Is there any way to make the width and height to zero including the paddings, so that it collapses completely?

```css
.test {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
 /* Setting width and height to zero. */
.test {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<p>Have a div with padding of 30px and width and height of 100px. Box sizing is set to border box. When trying to set the width and height to zero, it does not work. Element stays at 60px X 60px dimensions. (Even with the overflow set to hidden).</p>
<p>Any idea what's going on here? Is there any way to make the width and height to zero including the paddings, so that it collapses completely?</p>
```

Comment: remove padding  - padding inculcated in width

Comment: According the CSS box model, padding is present within the border. Thus this is normal behavior.

Comment: Why do you add a `padding` if you don't want that the `padding` is applied?

Comment: if you want to hide why can't you use `display:none`? can you tell me the scenario why you need this?

Comment: is there anyway to do it using a single call? Like $('.test').css('width': '0'); ?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I want to animate the height from the initial value to zero (including border and padding properties), then set it's display to none. Trying to mimic the behavior of $('element').slideUp()

Comment: in the same animation try to apply `padding:0`

Comment: @t.niese I want the animate a container element's height (whether or not it has a padding or border applied), then set it's display to none. Trying to replicate the jQuery's slideUp effect, using velocity js (as a learning exercise).

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai So, if we are to write a function like jQuery's slideUp, we need to take care of padding and the border (setting each property to zero, along with the height) I guess?

Comment: If you look at the 'box-sizing' : 'border-box' definition, it says "The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. " So when we set width to zero, shouldn't it include padding and border as well?

Answer (score 4):

According the [CSS box model](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/), padding is present within the border. Thus this is normal behavior. If you want to show `padding` only when the content is present, you can remove the element if the content is empty using [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

```css
.test {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Setting width and height to zero. */

.test {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.test:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

padding is also include in height and width padding:30px mean 30px from left,right,top and also from bottom
its mean your div actual size is 460X460 so you have to remove padding also in over write css

```
.test {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```css
.test {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
 /* Setting width and height to zero. */
.test {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<p>Have a div with padding of 30px and width and height of 100px. Box sizing is set to border box. When trying to set the width and height to zero, it does not work. Element stays at 60px X 60px dimensions. (Even with the overflow set to hidden).</p>
<p>Any idea what's going on here? Is there any way to make the width and height to zero including the paddings, so that it collapses completely?</p>
```

Comment: the `width` and `height` are set to `0` with the second rule so it is `60x60` and not `460x460`

Comment: this is just for explain your width and height is 400 each including padding its become 460 each and then you remove only width and height but padding 30px from 4 sides just remain

Answer (score 0):

You achieve what you want with a "single call" like this:

```
$('.test').css({ 'width': '0', height: '0', padding: '0' });
```

Your problem is the padding in combination with the border-box. Alternatively, you can use display: none, visibility: hidden or opacity: 0

Comment: used it for different purpose : hiding element and not having gap between form fields :)